# Go http server and global variables

Tags: go

I have a http server. It is written with Go.
I have this code:

```
package main
import (
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
)
var cur = 0
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cur = cur + 1;
}
func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":9010", nil)
}
```

Is it safe?
May be I need to use a mutex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not safe, yes you will need locking of some form.
Each connection is handled in its own goroutine. See [the Serve() implementation](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/http/server.go#L1538) for details.

A general pattern is to use a goroutine which checks for a channel and accepts changes
via a channel:

```
var counterInput = make(chan int)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    counterInput <- 1
}

func counter(c <- chan int) {
    cur := 0
    for v := range c {
        cur += v
    }
}

func main() {
    go counter(counterInput)
    // setup http
}
```

Related: [Is "net/http"'s use of global variables considered a good practice in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230643/is-net-https-use-of-global-variables-considered-a-good-practice-in-golang).

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm overlooking something, in this case, instead of using a lock (or a channel), you could use [the tools](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/) found in the `sync/atomic` package (though you'll need to make your type either `int32` or `int64`)

The documentation itself recommends you otherwise, though.

> These functions require great care to be used correctly. Except for special, low-level applications, synchronization is better done with channels or the facilities of the sync package. Share memory by communicating; don't communicate by sharing memory.